# quadrotor with laser scanner?

Tags: ros, quadcopter, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got tired of looking for quadrotor that supports laser scanner with reasonable price. I mean here at least < 5000 $. I came across a company that makes Asctec Pelican and other quadrotors. They did send me the list of the prices. The prices are absolutely crazy, more than 10,000 Euro.  I don't want fancy quadrotor with sophisticated laser scanners. Just quadrotor that has reasonable laser scanner ( the laser's price < 1500 $) and I will be able to gather data to PC easily. I came across a bunch of laser scanners  [here](http://www.robotshop.com/en/laser-scanners-rangefinders.html). Some of them are good to my budget but I want a laser scanner with quadrotor as a one package. Please suggest me any platform that suits my needs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166201/quadrotor-with-laser-scanner?/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2014-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While some prices might seem high at first sight, you´ll also get a very mature system when willing to pay the price (and it seems a lot of people around the world are willing to do so), so I wouldn´t call prices "crazy", just not super affordable or so ;) .

If you´re on a tighter budget it is certainly possible to acquire a cheaper platform that also is quite capable, but the support and development burden will be on you. In recent years, a lot of quadrotor platforms came out that are quite capable of carrying a LIDAR in principle. Adding a small ARM-based board like the [UDOO](http://www.udoo.org/) or [Pandaboard](http://pandaboard.org/) allows reading LIDAR data or even doing onboard processing. Depending on the amount of work you want to perform yourself, it should be possible to mount a LIDAR to many platforms, provided they can lift enough payload.

Examples of LIDARs used on less pricy platforms (although the heavier Mikrokopters also are not the cheapest):

- http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/MoD/ (MikroKopter based)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhrCuN4eUJo (I believe also Mikrokopter)
- https://github.com/NIFTi-Fraunhofer/nifti_uav (MikroKopter)
- http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/ardupilot-mega-with-ros-onboard (Arducopter)
- https://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/E-project/Available/E-project-042711-122042/unrestricted/Final_Report_CDR.pdf (Mikrokopter, very detailed report by WPI)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2014-05-17**:
First of all, thank you for the reply. I've checked all of them. It is not clear whether they are willing to sell the platforms. It seems they designed the quadrotors with no information about the cost nor their availability to be sold out.

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2014-05-17**:
Some of quadrotors are not expensive, so with the link that I've posted in my post some laser scanners 2D are not expensive. So it might be not impossible if there is a whole package. I just wonder.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-05-17**:
That´s kind of the point: The less costly way is buying the different parts and building/assembling the complete platform yourself. There are a lot of quadrotor platforms out there, but no "cheap" integrated system featuring quadrotor, LIDAR and onboard computer.

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2014-05-17**:
When I say cheap, I mean in a range 5000 $ which is still expensive.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-05-18**:
Asctec is the only company I know of that sells a complete package with or prepared for mounting a LIDAR. Come to think of it, it might be better to ask on a UAV related site, as this really is not about ROS.

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2014-05-18**:
Hey there, the uav in the second video is indeed a Mikrokopter (Quadro XL). It's around 1000 euros (+remote). Mounting e.g. a pandaboard (~180 eur) and a beginner level hokuyo (~1000 eur) is quiet easy, I didn't have access to a 3d printer at the time and managed with some wood, a saw and a drill.

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2014-05-18**:
However, you should seriously (re)consider using a 2d lidar on an uav. Especially if you go for a "cheap" 5m laser. It has some major drawbacks imho (e.g. range and rectilinearity assumption), and visual slam nowadays works pretty well, while cameras are usually cheaper than time of flight sensors.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-05-19**:
But visual SLAM needs a depth camera(Kinect etc), then outdoor application is not possible ;-)

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2014-05-19**:
you can also use a 2d cam: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZChzEcLNzI

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-05-19**:
@jodafo: Thanks for the link, any ROS package is available to do that?

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2014-05-21**:
unfortunately not

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-05-21**:
@jodafo: Thanks for the information